# What is faster in php: syslog, file append or error_log

Tags: php, syslog

Are there any experiences on what is faster in php (i.e. less overhead, less time):

- syslog()
- error_log()
- explicit file open(), append, close()

Thanks.

Comment: my experience: it is definitely not explicit file open append close. syslog is a demon process which is optimized for logging and is very fast. error_log also uses syslog to log depending on configuration. It all depends on configuration

Comment: Writing no logs at all would be faster. But would that be bright? After actually **profiling** *your* application, you'll find that there are more optimize-worthy parts.

Comment: @mario - yes I know - battle against the millisecs .... We're using that also for tracing down a lot on staging, also for profiling. On production it's anyway only set to error logging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`syslog` will show differences in it's performance, depending on the configuration of the syslog daemon. For example, messages might get duplicated into several log files or even sent over the net. Therefore it is not really comparable with the others.

Using PHP's `error_log()` or implementing file based logging on your own shouldn't show differences in it's performance (having that you implemented it efficiently). However, I expect `error_log()` a bit faster since it is simple and written in C, but a custom file based implementation might be more flexible, configurable and produce *better/fancier* messages.

At the end you would need to benchmark and compare those solutions having a real world use case.

Comment: Actually there are only marginal diffs between explicit file and error_log, thus I changed to error_log since that's the supposed way to write messages.